# Why AngularJS routes are not working in local?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have html file which implements AngularJS routes as follows,

**index.html:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-view>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script>  
  // Code goes here
var demo = angular.module('demo', ['ngRoute']);
demo.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    controller: 'testController',
    templateUrl: 'test.html'
  })
})    
var controllers = {};
controllers.testController = function($scope){
   $scope.first = "Info";
    $scope.customers=[
        {name:'jerry',city:'chicago'},
        {name:'tom',city:'houston'},
        {name:'enslo',city:'taipei'}
    ];
}
demo.controller(controllers)
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.html:

```
 <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
    </br>
    {{first}}
    </br> 
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name">{{cust.name | uppercase}} - {{cust.city}}</li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

You can find the working version [here](http://runnable.com/me/VBgClIU-ZakCu23W)

But why is it not working when I run the same in my local browser :(

Here is the chrome console error:

[image]

Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: Check your browser console for errors. To be specific, `Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Probably it is blocking and not loading the view..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to make it clear. For security reasons, Chrome (for example) won't allow you to load local files (ie: the templates for your views). My suggestion is to set up a web server to test your applications:

1. Use the free edition of the [Visual Studio Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd537667(v=vs.100).aspx) for web development.
2. Use [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/) to quickly set up your project.

Alternatively you can use inline templates in place of loading it externally, but it does not seems to be a good practice.

Edit:

Using the console error print that you posted, Chrome is blocking your ajax request. You can bypass this restriction using a command line argument:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

However I would encourage you to set up a simple local web server, It will prevent you for some headaches while your are learning...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firefox for test. Route and ajax will work.
But it is better to set up a web server like @gustavodidomenico said

Answer (score 0):

the work around to make ng-view work in local is to put the content of other htmls in the script tag as

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="index22.html">
This is index 2 template.
</script>

 <script type="text/ng-template" id="index33.html">
  This is index 3 template.
 </script>
```

in the same HTML from where the call is being made.

ngview makes an AJAX call to load the content of external HTMLs or seperate HTMLs , chrome does not allow AJAX call for local resources , IE 11 also shows 'Access is denied' error message.

when including in script tags , this AJAX call is not made.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Chrome Extension` called [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en). you can add it and then lunch it, in browse dialog choose your working folder, then it gives you a `Local URL`, you can test your app there.