# ngRoute not finding template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I'm new to angular and am having a hard time getting ngRoute to pick up my template file.

Here is my index.html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
</head>
<nav>
    <div>
        <ul>
             <li><a href="#/home">home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<body>
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Here is my app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Hello World';
});

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
}]);
```

Here is my pages/home.html:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>    
</div>
```

I can see that it is appending #/ to the root url so perhaps this is partially working; however, it doesn't seem to be rendering the template at "pages/home.html".

I've checked the cdn url's to make sure there wasn't any version inconsistencies, and what not, but that doesn't seem the be the case.

This is pretty much my first Angular project, and I've just been going off of the docs, but there must be something I'm not seeing. Coming from other server side projects, the lack of stack trace is killing me haha.

Is there something I'm missing in the above code, that is preventing my template from being rendered in '/'?

Thanks!

Comment: for removing the #, you need to use html5Mode(true) or this can also be achieved by using .htaccess.

Comment: are you able to get it working?

Comment: I'm still unable to get this working. index.html redirects to /index.html#/ and remains blank. Same result for when I modify to use html5Mode(true);

Comment: Try to include your jquery-min.js above the angular js script. Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: Good call on the console. I'm getting: angular.js:12416 Error: [$location:nobase] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$location/nobase

Comment: @chrisl0lz you don't need to add any location service and html5Mode routing. you only need html5mode routing when you want to remove # in the URL.  Your problem is different. Look at my solution

Comment: Just edited my code in the question to reflect my most recent attempt.

Comment: Most recent attempt threw this guy in the console logs: angular.js:10661 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/chris/Git/slcc-eportfolio/pages/home.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: @chrisl0lz  like I said you don't need html5Mode routing. Go back to your original code and just change  .when('/') to  .when('/home').

Comment: @WildWidow okay trying now

Comment: The problem was that Chrome chokes on local files, my answer contains the details.

Comment: Thanks @AfshanShujat for pointing me towards the console.

Comment: Thanks @WildWidow for keeping my routes on track.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code and it is working fine, you cam take help from it.

```
var EventList = angular.module("EventList", ['ngRoute' ,'infinite-scroll']);
EventList.config(function($routeProvider) {
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); 
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/business/business_home_events.html',
            controller: 'EventListController'
         });
});

EventList.controller('EventListController', ['$scope',  '$http', '$route', function($scope,  $http, $route){

        // Do your work

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with your `when ('/')`. Since your url has `#/home` - it looks in the `.when` to find that route.

change it to

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {          // <-
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

Comment: I noticed this as well and changed my url to "#/" with no luck.

Comment: @chrisl0lz don't change your URL, your url should be #/home, change your .when('/') to .when('/home')

Answer (score 0):

I have executed you code and is working fine on mozilla.

However, there is an issue in chrome of cross origin request if we run the file without putting in server.

But it is working fine on chrome also if you will put it on server (may be xampp/wampp) and run the file. The angular library you are using have http request to another server.

Answer (score 0):

This was an annoying one, but I think I figured it out.

I was encountering this issue while testing locally (no nodejs) on Chrome; however, sure enough when I popped it open in Safari it was working. It seems that ngRoute chokes on local files in Chrome.

I found a reference to the issue here, which is closed, <strike>so I'm guessing if I update to a newer version I shouldn't have this issue.</strike>

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4680

**Setting up a web server should resolve this problem.**

[Why AngularJS routes are not working in local?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867408/why-angularjs-routes-are-not-working-in-local)